# Avoid to Remove Duplicate value from JSON Array response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**I have array of image id**

```
  1005
  1003
  1001
  997
  994
  992
  983
  981
  979
  977
  975
  972
 1048
 1048
 857
 857
 817
 797
 1046
 751
```

**when i request these id's like**

```
http:/example.in/wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=50&orderby=include&include[]=1005&include[]=1157&include[]=1145&include[]=1140&include[]=1089&include[]=1085&include[]=857&include[]=1007&include[]=1005&include[]=1003&include[]=1001&include[]=997&include[]=994&include[]=992&include[]=983&include[]=981&include[]=979
```

**JsonArray response remove the duplicate id's i.e 1048 and 857 but i do not want to remove that so how can i achive that.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, You are asking how to add values to be duplicated not to be identical, I think this is backend issue, to avoid it you need to push the values to the array like this in `php`:

```
array_push(values, 123);
array_push(values, 12);
array_push(values, 123);
```

the response will be:

```
[ 123, 12, 123 ]
```

Comment: sorry dear i do not want to remove duplicate value rather than i want to get duplicate response so that i can get same media two times because i need it

Comment: so you need your response to be cleared from duplicates ?

Comment: No i want duplicate value but JSON array response does not give me duplicates i.e i am requesting 50 media but it give me 48 response because it  make two 1048 and 857 as one respectively